# Calculate if point lies inside spherical sector

Tags: geometry

I would like to calculate if a point $P$ in $\mathbb R^3$ space lies inside a spherical sector, where the radius of the sphere is $r$ and the height of the cap is $h$. Is there an elegant way to calculate this? Or should the spherical sector be broken down into simpler shapes: a cone and a sphere, and individual calculations done for each shape?

Comment: Inside the sphere *and* inside the (unbounded) cone.

Comment: How are the bounds of the spherical sector defined? Can you please add an example?

Comment: @MathLover Sorry I don't know how to answer this question. Here is an example of spherical sector I had in mind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector#/media/File:Kugel-sektor.png.

Comment: yes I understand that part but how are you fixing its coordinates because all you have is radius of the sphere and $h$ and that does not uniquely identify a spherical sector. So, as long as a point is inside the sphere, it will be in one of the spherical sectors of given dimension. Is its axis along $z$ axis?

Comment: @MathLover My bad, sorry! Yes it's also defined by some arbitrary axis, $z$ (I hope you don't mean the coordinate system's $z$ axis)

Comment: Yes that works. It is easier to first convert the problem statement to spherical coordinates. If you have been given an arbitrary axis, say making angle $\phi$ with $z$ axis and $\theta$ with x axis, we can build equations to check whether the given point is in the spherical sector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spherical coordinates,

$x = \rho \cos \theta \sin \phi, y = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi, z = \rho \cos\phi, \rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

If the radius of the sphere is $r$ with origin as the center, height of spherical cap is $h$ and radius of the base of the spherical cap is $a$, then the vertex angle of the cone is given by,

$\alpha = \displaystyle \small \arctan \big(\frac{a}{r-h}\big)$ and the spherical sector is defined by,

$\displaystyle 0 \leq \rho \leq r, \small \phi_a - \frac{\alpha}{2} \leq \phi \leq \phi_a + \frac{\alpha}{2}, \theta_a - \frac{\alpha}{2} \leq \theta \leq \theta_a + \frac{\alpha}{2} \ $ where $\phi_a, \theta_a$ define the axis of the spherical sector.

Now for a given point $\displaystyle \small P(x_p, y_p, z_p), $

$\displaystyle \small \rho_p = \sqrt{x_p^2 + y_p^2 + z_p^2}, \ \phi_p = \arccos \big(\frac{z_p}{\rho_p}\big), \ \theta_p = \arccos \big(\frac{x_p}{\rho_p \sin \phi_p} \big) $

So for the point $P$ to be in the spherical sector,

$\displaystyle \small 0 \leq \rho_p \leq r, \  \phi_a - \frac{\alpha}{2} \leq \phi_p \leq \phi_a + \frac{\alpha}{2}, \theta_a - \frac{\alpha}{2} \leq \theta_p \leq \theta_a + \frac{\alpha}{2}$

Comment: Thanks very much! I guess we can follow the same logic to also calculate a circular sector with an arbitrary axis for point $P$
in $\mathbb R^2$ space, but with polar coordinates instead of spherical coordinates.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In cylindrical coordinates with the cone axis along $z$,

$$\begin{cases}\rho^2+z^2\le r^2,\\\rho\le\alpha z.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask what $α$ denotes?

Comment: @LennyWhite: your task to relate $\alpha$ to $h$.

Answer (score 0):

In Cartesian coordinates, if $\hat{a}$ is the cone unit axis vector ($\left\lVert\hat{a}\right\rVert = 1$), $\vec{o}$ is the center of the sphere, $r$ is the sphere radius, and either $\varphi$ is half the apex angle (aperture angle $2\varphi$) or $h$ is the cap height,
$$\cos\varphi = \frac{r - h}{r} \quad \iff \quad h = r (1 - \cos\varphi)$$
Let
$$S^2 = (\sin\varphi)^2 = 1 - (\cos\varphi)^2 = \frac{2 r h - h^2}{r^2}$$
Then, point $\vec{p}$ is in the spherical sector if
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
q & = (\vec{p} - \vec{o}) \cdot \hat{a} \ge 0 \\
d^2 & = \left\lVert \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right\rVert^2 \le r^2 \\
q^2 & \le S^2 d^2 \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
Here, $d$ is the distance squared from sphere center to point $\vec{p}$, and $q$ is the distance from the sphere center to point $\vec{p}$ measured along the cone axis. $q$ is zero at the center, and positive in the same halfspace as the cone. The last ensures that the point $\vec{p}$ is within the cone, by ensuring that $q/d \le \sin\varphi$.

The reason for using Euclidean norm squared is to avoid having to compute square roots (useful when programming), as $\left\lVert\vec{p}\right\rVert^2 = \vec{p} \cdot \vec{p}$.